# Case statements are bringing up multiple alerts at a time

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that is supposed to be clicked three times and have three different alerts for each click. However, what is happening is that it takes two clicks to even begin the process and after say the third click(which is supposed to be the second) the second alert comes up and the first alert comes back up.

How can I fix this?

I have tried

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function something(){
var counter = 0;
var button = document.querySelector("#button");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
counter++;
switch(counter) {
    case 1:
  alert("something");
  break;
    case 2:
        alert("something else");
        break;
    case 3:
        alert("something else else");
        break;
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="button" value="enter" type="button" onclick="something();">
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the alerts to start after the first click of the button, and stop after three and not bring up the previous alerts after each click.

Comment: why did you added `click` event listener to button within the function? There is already `onclick` attached to the input element.

Comment: I kept getting a bunch of errors and that somehow fixed it. Do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Your script has unbalanced brackets. You didn't terminate the anonymous function, the call to `addEventListener`, or the `something` function.

Comment: It's definitely the problem Every time you click, you add another click listener, and they all run the next time you click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button has an `onclick` attribute which calls the function `something()`. But, every time the function `something()` runs, it re-initializing counter to 0 and adding a new event listener to the button. This is why you see multiple dialogues. You only need one event listener.

Additionally, your JavaScript is missing closing brackets.

You need to choose whether to use `onclick` or to simply add an event listener. Here's a working example using only `onclick`. Note that I've also moved the `counter` declaration to the global level so that it isn't re-declared on every click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var counter = 0;
function something(){
  counter++;
  switch(counter) {
    case 1:
      alert("something");
      break;
    case 2:
      alert("something else");
      break;
    case 3:
      alert("something else else");
      break;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="button" value="enter" type="button" onclick="something();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you!